# MC34063 boost circuit drops voltage when adding load resistor in LTspice

Tags: raspberry-pi, ltspice, boost, voltage, mc34063

I am using LTspice to simulate a [MC34063](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) boost circuit to bring a 3.7 V Lipo battery up to 5 V in order to power a Raspberry Pi Zero.

When I simulate the circuit it works just fine (shown in the first picture):

[image: first]

However, when I add a load resistor representing the Raspberry Pi Zero, the voltage drops back down to 3.7 V (shown in the second picture):

[image: second]

I have been trying to troubleshoot this circuit problem. Maybe there is a glaring mistake that someone sees that I don’t.

The math for the load resistor:
V / I = R, (voltage with the load at ~3.74 V) / (~0.1 A) = ~37.4 Ω

I got ~0.1 A from [this site](https://www.cnx-software.com/2021/12/09/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-power-consumption/).

I got ~3.74 V from measuring the voltage with the load.

Please tell me what you think; I would greatly appreciate feedback.

Edit:
This where I got my model the circuit was originally for buck circuit  but I changed it to a boost
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/simulate-mc34063-on-ltspice/

Comment: Your feedback resistors are too small, comparable to the load. Add an order of magnitude or two (I'm referring mainly at `R3`).

Comment: Where did you get the model from? I found one from Onsemi, but it's riddled with problems, and I'm not really in the mood for fixing.

Comment: Hi a concern citizen,
I got my model from the ti datasheet linked on MC34063. I tried changing R3 from 330ohm to 3.3k and 33k and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: (when replying to someone, use `@`, otherwise the user don't get notifications, so they might miss the reply/-ies. Use `@<TAB>` to cycle between a list of available names, they should appear without any spaces. If `<TAB>` doesn't bring up any list then there's no need for `@`. The owner of the post is always notified.)

Comment: I still can't find where you got your model from.  The TI page for the MC34063A doesn't list any models.  The [MC33063A page does](https://www.ti.com/product/MC33063A), but they're Pspice models.  Did you use one of those but then draw your own LTspice symbol for it?

Comment: Hi @SteKulov, Sorry when you said model I was confused earlier. I got my model online. I am adding the file for the LTspice circuit to my post at the bottom.

Comment: Also thank you a concerned citizen thank you for the tip! I am still new to this. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ritz123  Thanks for the link.  I have problems with that model too.  Please use the one a concerned citizen used in his answer.

Comment: As a tip for LTSpice - use windows vertically tiled so the schematic is larger and easier to read.

Comment: @PStechPaul  Tile horizontally you mean?  Elongate the windows vertically so they tile (i.e. stack up against each other) horizontally.

Comment: Yes. Just click on "Window" in the menu and choose "Tile Vertically". And use the "Space" bar to fill the window with the schematic.

Answer (score 2):

For one, the feedback resistors (`R3, R4`) have low values that, when the load is added, they will influence the value of the load (it will be less).

The value for the capacitor `C1` implies a `ton` of 3 μs, but the maximum frequency for the MC34063, as listed in the datasheet, is 100 kHz. A value of 1 nF gives a typical 33 kHz, so `C1` will force the chip to switch at a much higher frequency. Building a switched-mode supply is really something that needs an oscilloscope so, if you have one, do check the oscillation.

The value for the current sense is quite low for a 0.1 A load. I don't know how you calculated it, but if you look on [TI's datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf), on page 14 you have a table with some design equations. Even the voltage divider seems off if you want a 5 V output. I imposed a 75 kHz switching frequency, a 3.3 V minimum input voltage, and what I get is this:

```
ton  = 10.5u
toff = 28.6u
C    = 420p
Ipk  = 0.357
Rsc  = 0.84
L    = 82u
```

Use 430 pF for the capacitor. And for the divider, with `R1 = 11k  =>  R2 = 33k`, choose 33.2 kΩ. The initial model I found was from Onsemi, but it's riddled with problems, so I found another one made by (the unfortunately late) analogspiceman, [here](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Simulating_the_MC34063_in_Inverter_Configuration_with_an_Accurate_TL431A_Model). I modified the Zener to have `Roff = 550` because the reference was lower than 1.25 V. In rest, this is how it simulates for me:

[image: 34063 boost]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation a concerned citizen! I will be redoing my math for my calculated values.

Comment: The question was edited to link to the model they used which seems to be the Onsemi one, but modified by Helmut.  Just a FYI, I can't get it to work either.  The model you linked to seems to be much more stable.

Comment: @SteKulov Looks like Helmut simply converted the behavioural expressions to avoid the ternary operator. LTspice can handle it as long as it's not nested. It's most probably  parser thing. Analogspiceman was very good with modelling and control was his speciality. A pity he's gone.

Comment: @Ritz123 Those values should work for your case, since it was with your conditions that I calculated them. But, it never hurts to double-check.